# Can I customize the `resources` helper in my routes to use a parameter other than \:id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a route that looks like this:

```
get '/sell/:ticker', to: 'sell#new', as: 'sell'
```

That does what I want, which is allows `get` requests to `myapp.com/sell/ABC`.

I have another route, `resources :stocks` that I would also like to be able to specify for it to use `/:ticker`, rather than `/:id` in all the routes.

Is there some way for me to modify the `resources` helper to use `\:ticker` rather than `\:id`, without having to write every route individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should be able to use the `param` in routes file as,

```
resources :stocks, param: :ticker
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm!! Thanks bruv.

Comment: glad to be of help, would you accept the answer ? @marcamillion

Comment: Yep there was a time delay, where I had to wait.